# Concatenate integer year, string month and string day to form BirthDate based on condition using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

1. How can i say to pandas dataframe

```
if df['BirthDateFlag'] == 'Year' then
   df['BirthDate'] = df['YearOfBirth'].map(str) + '-01' + '-01'
```

output will be: 2001-01-01

2. how can i convert it to date format?

Thanks

Comment: Start with `df[df['BirthdateFlag'] == 'Year']` -- that's how you operate on the rows of a dataframe that meet a condition.

Answer (score 0):

You code is equivalent (in meaning) to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BirthDateFlag': ['Year', 'other'],
                   'YearOfBirth': [2023, float('nan')]})

m = df['BirthDateFlag'].eq('Year')

df.loc[m, 'BirthDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[m, 'YearOfBirth'], format='%Y')
```

Output:

```
  BirthDateFlag  YearOfBirth  BirthDate
0          Year       2023.0 2023-01-01
1         other          NaN        NaT
```